# How can I remove the "Capitulo" (chapter) word in Headings?

Tags: sectioning, page-numbering

Im writing a document in LaTeX, but I found a problem with long chapter titles and headings, because I see that the page number is too near to the chapter title (due to its extension)

Can I modify these headings in order to separate both numbers and header title? For example, removing the Capitulo (Chapter) word from the header title.

Here you got an example in order to describe my problem.
[image: Example]

Sorry for my bad expression, Im Spanish.

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange! Can you please add the code that produces the output to your question? Otherwise it can be difficult to guess exactly how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks!

I dont have any specific code that produce that output. It's the standard behaviour of LaTeX (Im using the default book template). The part of that screenshot is the top part of the page on even pages.

Comment: You can easily define  an own page style, or redefine an existing page style, with `titleps` (which comes with `titlesec`).

Comment: Try `\chapter[toc & header title]{Title in the document}`  to put a short version of the chapter title in the header (and the ToC).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` classes) then:

```
% headerprob.tex  SE 561234
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeheadrule{ruled}{0pt}{0pt} % eliminate the rule from the ruled pagestyle
\pagestyle{ruled} % does not include Chapter
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Otherwise I think that you would have to define your own pagestyle which would involve changing the `\chapter` definition which you would probably not want to do unless you are an expert.